# Viewing the color (#xxxxxx) of the element under the cursor

Tags: vim

*What would be the easiest way to view the color values (guifg and guibg) of the highlighting element that the cursor is currently on?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For syntax script development (why else would you need the editor color?), you'll also need the syntax group and linked highlight group names. The [SyntaxAttr plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) provides this in a nice mapping, e.g.:

```
group: vimUserFuncName guifg=DarkCyan(#008b8b) gui=bold
```

Comment: I'm trying to write a plugin for something that has something to do with colours, so this is an easy way for me to get the value underneath.

Comment: This doesn't do quite what I had in mind, but I think I'll manage to scrape off some parts of it that will be useful to finish what I started. Thanks Ingo!

Answer (score 2):

Figures, found it in help. In case anyone ever needs this ...

```
nmap <F11> :call <SID>SynColour()<CR>

function! <SID>SynColour()
echo "guibg = ".synIDattr(synIDtrans( synID(line("."), col("."), 1) ), "bg#").", guifg = ".synIDattr(synIDtrans( synID(line("."), col("."), 1) ), "fg#")
endfunction
```